# preferred implementation style for factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

what is your preferred implementation style for a factory pattern? For example, consider a website where I want to use a factory pattern to save to 2+ external systems.  This is my first impression for a clean implementation:

- Create a class named `ExternalSystemManagerFactory`
- In the constructor of this class pass in an enumeration to indicate the target external system.  For example:  `ExternalSystemManager.System1` or `ExternalSystemManager.System2`
- Create a property on this class named `ExternalSystemManager` of type `IExternalSystemManager`
- The constructor would set this property value based on the constructor argument
- Create a method stub on `IExternalSystemManager` named `SaveToExternalSystem`
- Create 2 concrete classes for my external systems that implement `IExternalSystemManager` (`EsmSystem1`, `EsmSystem2`)

Then in my client class, I could save to ExternalSystem1 like this:

```
new ExternalSystemManagerFactory(ExternalSystemManager.System1).ExternalSystemManager.SaveToExternalSystem();
```

Does this seem like a reasonable implementation?  Do you see any potential issues with this implementation?  Is this a fairly common implementation style or is there a general trend towards a different implementation style?

Comment: You should read up on the gang of four factory pattern. You should focus on why to use the factory pattern. That should be enough for you to evaluate if your solution fits the pattern. In any case this question is primarily opinion-based and isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion when it comes to patterns, it typically has to do with how it "feels" when you use it.  If you are comfortable with accessing your data in the way you have written it, then by all means go for it.  I'm a firm believer that there really isn't a perfect way to implement a pattern and I actually avoid them unless my code blatantly has a need and they emerge naturally.  So my advice is...Don't force it, but if it feel good, then do it.

Comment: This is a very good point in my opinion. Being a creative task, programming *does* rely on subjective criteria as well. A solution can be correct and elaborate,  but is worthless if you don't *like* it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you describe is ok, if it is only about two implementations. If the number of external systems that you want to access increases, you'd always have to change

- the enum
- the `switch` statement in the constructor that chooses the concrete implementation.

In the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that the Gang of Four describes, you'd get rid of the enum and implement it like this:

- An abstract base class/interface for the factory.
- An implementation of the factory for each concrete external system.
- You create the concrete factory at one spot in your code and always access it through the interface.

An advantage of this implementation is that you can easily configure which factory to create instead of using a switch statement in your code. Besides that you wouldn't have to adjust the switch statement each time you connect a new external system, it also allows you to create implementations for new systems without touching the assembly of the factory at all.

Another approach you might want to consider if you have lots of dependencies you want to create is to use an [Inversion of Control Container](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). You register the types that should be created for an interface at the beginning of your application and ask the IOC container if you need an instance or inject it in the constructors of the classes. There are several IOC containers available, e.g. Microsoft Unity, Ninject, AutoFac, .... This will save you lots of time if you have several or huge factories.